# Expected value of Cumulative Hazard

Tags: probability, self-learning

Define $T=\min(T^0,C)$ where $T^0$ is the failure time and $C$ is the censoring time. Define the failure indicator $$\delta = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $T^0\leq C$}\\ 0 & \text{if $T^0> C$}\end{cases}$$ Furthermore, let $\Lambda(t)$ be the cumulative hazard function for $T^0$. Assume the random censorship model. Show that $\text{E}[\delta] = \text{E}[\Lambda(T)]$.

First approach

$$\begin{align*}
\text{E}[\delta] &= \text{Pr}\left\{ T^0 \leq C\right\}\\
&= \int_0^\infty \int_0^c f_{T^0,C}(t,c)dtdc\\
&= \int_0^\infty \int_0^c f_{T^0}(t)f_C(c)dtdc\\
&= \int_0^\infty \int_t^\infty f_{T^0}(t)f_C(c)dcdt\\
&= \int_0^\infty f_{T^0}(t)\int_t^\infty f_C(c)dcdt\\
&= 
\end{align*}$$ I get stuck here. Another approach is $$\begin{align*}
\text{E}[\Lambda(T)] &= \int_0^\infty \Lambda(t)f_{T^0}(t)dt\\
&= \int_0^\infty \int_0^t\dfrac{f_{T^0}(x)}{S_{T^0}(x)}f_{T^0}(t)dxdt\\
&= \int_0^\infty \int_0^t\dfrac{f_{T^0}(x)}{S_{T^0}(x)}f_{T^0}(t)dxdt\\
&= \int_0^\infty \dfrac{f_{T^0}(x)}{S_{T^0}(x)}\int_x^\infty f_{T^0}(t)dtdx\\
&= \int_0^\infty \dfrac{f_{T^0}(x)}{S_{T^0}(x)}S_{T^0}(x)dx\\
&= 1
\end{align*}$$ This does not seem right...so I am lost. Can anyone help? Let me know if you need clarification on any of the terms.

Comment: Sorry, for self-learning problems its standard for the poster to provide atleast an initial attempt at the problem. I was too busy to type up all of my work, but still wanted to post the problem in hopes that it would give somebody some time to think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

$$\begin{align*}
\text{E}[\Lambda_T(T)] &= \int_0^\infty \Lambda_T(t)f_T(t)dt\\
&= \int_0^C \Lambda_T(t)f_T(t)dt + \int_C^\infty \Lambda_T(C)f_T(t)dt\\
&= \int_0^C -\log{S_T(t)}f_T(t)dt + \Lambda_T(C)\int_C^\infty f_T(t)dt\\
&= \int_0^{-\log{S_T(C)}} ue^{-u}du + \Lambda_T(C)S_T(C)\\
&= \left[ -ue^{-u} - e^{-u}\right]_0^{-\log S_T(C)} +  \Lambda_T(C)S_T(C)\\
&= (\log S_T(C))S_T(C) - S_T(C) + 1 + \Lambda_T(C)S_T(C)\\
&= -\Lambda_T(C)S_T(C)  - S_T(C) + 1 + \Lambda_T(C)S_T(C)\\
&= 1-S_T(C)\\
&= F_T(C)\\
&= \text{Pr}\left\{ T^0 \leq C\right\}\\
&= \text{E}[\delta]
\end{align*}$$